# pass filter options to the Javascript filter method

Tags: javascript

Suppose a user wants to see a list of musicians based on setting the following booleans:

```
english_filter = true; // ("EN")
spanish_filter = false; // ("ES")
underground_filter = true; // ("underground")
famous_filter = true; // ("famous")
```

In the case above, the user chooses to see musicians that speak english and is either famous or underground.

based on these settings, I want to filter an array called customArray.

```
function applyFilters(el) {
   return el.language === "EN" &&  (el.popularity === 'famous' || el.popularity === 'underground');
}

var filtered = customArray.filter(applyFilters);
```

this is an example of the "el" structure passed to applyFilters:

```
{
id: "sHYNYKFENX"
language: "EN"
name: "John Smith"
popularity: "famous"
profile_image:"https://google.com/fakeimage.jpeg"
recording_handle: "DvYenMhJ8Mo"
recording_title: "Awesome song"
}
```

The code above works, but I'd like to abstract it so that the user can choose whatever combination he wants. How could I create a function to accomplish this?

### Thank you so much

UPDATE:

Thanks you for all the answers - I think we are close. Here are some expected results:

```
var english_filter = false; // ("EN")
var spanish_filter = false; // ("ES")
var underground_filter = false; // ("underground")
var famous_filter = false; // ("famous")
```

All musicians should be listed.

```
var english_filter = false; // ("EN")
var spanish_filter = false; // ("ES")
var underground_filter = true; // ("underground")
var famous_filter = false; // ("famous")
```

Only underground musicians, regardless of what language they speak.

---

If possible, it'd be great to craft a solution that allows for whatever language you pass it, not just english and spanish. (Not required though). Thank you so much everyone. You are all brilliant.

Comment: what are the possible combinations?

Comment: What does the el contain?

Comment: If you want whatever language to be returned, then take a look at my answer. You just have to not set the "language" property on `filters` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use dynamic filters such as:

```js
var filters = { language: "EN" };

// or
var filters = { language: "EN", popularity: "famous" };

// or using an array to indicate more than one option
var filters = {
    language: [
        "EN",
        "ES"
    ],
    popularity: "famous"
};
```

So, you'd have to write a function to read the options and compare to each objects properties:

```
function applyFilters(elem, filters) {
    var value, name, objectHasThisProperty, propertyHasValue;
    for(name in filters) {
        value = filters[name];

        objectHasThisProperty = elem.hasOwnProperty(name);
        propertyHasValue = isArray(value) ? inArray(elem[name], value) : elem[name] == value;

        if (!objectHasThisProperty || !propertyHasValue) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
var filtered = customArray.filter(function(elem) {
    return applyFilters(elem, filters)
});
```

Plus the two helper functions:

```
function isArray(variable) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(variable) === '[object Array]';
}
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1;
}
```

See it in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa6cr9p7/2/).

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted to see musicians that speak either spanish or english?

Answer (score 0):

Howabout

```
var filters = {
  english: { prop:"language", val:"EN", enabled: true},
  spanish: { prop:"language", val:"ES", enabled: false},
  underground: { prop:"popularity", val:"underground", enabled: true},
  famous: { prop:"popularity", val:"famous", enabled: false}
};

function applyFilters(el) {
   for (var i in filters) {
     var f = filters[i];
     if (filters.hasOwnProperty(f) && f.enabled && el[f.prop] !== f.val) return false;
   }
   return true;
}

var filtered = customArray.filter(applyFilters);
```

And you can set them like

```
filters.spanish.enabled = true;
```

Comment: You should use `filters[f]` instead of `f`. And `underground_filter && famous_filter` should mean `el.popularity === 'famous' || el.popularity === 'underground'` but your code checks `el.popularity === 'famous' && el.popularity === 'underground'`

Comment: Thank you both - @Oriol can you please illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @user1683056 I mean that if both underground and famous filters are enabled, according to your question you want to get the items that are either famous OR underground. But this code will return the ones which are famous AND underground, so there won't be any match.

Comment: Ah I missed that requirement. And the accepted answer was pretty much a derivate of mine so it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly,

```
function applyFilters(el) {
   return (
     !english_filter && !spanish_filter
     ||
     english_filter && el.language === "EN"
     ||
     spanish_filter && el.language === "ES"
   ) && (
     !underground_filter && !famous_filter
     ||
     underground_filter && el.popularity === 'underground'
     ||
     famous_filter && el.popularity === 'famous'
   );
}
```